# Difference between clearing a check and hold on funds

Tags: united-states, banking, deposits, terminology, checking-account

Quick question on banking terminology:

Can a check deposited in a U.S. bank *clear*, but still have the funds be subject to a *hold*?

Or are *clearing* and *not having a hold* the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check clears when the receiving bank successfully pulled the money from the issuing account.

However, the receiving bank may hold the money for an additional time before giving it to you. Sometimes this is done for good reasons (to prevent [Check kiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_kiting)) and sometimes this is about the bank having the money interest free for a bit, or just their own processing convenience.